# Simple plain JavaScript MVC

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am building a simple script to understand how mvc works. I'm new to this and like to see if anyone out there can help me with this. I can't get my render function to display the content from the model. I get an error in my console:

"app.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

Any help with this would be appreciated.

```js
var model = {
 farm: {
  cow: "Moo!", 
  pig: "Oink!", 
  duck: "Quack!"
 }
};

var controller = {
 init: function() {
  farmView.init();
 },
 getBarn: function() {
  return model.farm;
 }
};

 
var farmView = {
  
  init: function() {
   this.barn = document.getElementById('farm');
   this.render();
  },
  
  render: function() {
   var animals = controller.getBarn();
   var examplediv = document.getElementById('cow');
   this.barn.innerHTML = '';
   var htmlStr = '';
   htmlStr += '<span>' + model.farm.cow + '</span>' + '<span>' + model.farm.pig + '</span>';

   this.barn.appendChild(htmlStr);
   examplediv.appendChild(htmlStr);
   
  }
  
};
 
controller.init();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Farmcow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="farm">
  <div id="cow"></div>
 </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error message seems to say it clearly, what you pass as an argument to the appendChild is not of a Node type. You possibly meant to call createElement to have a new element, set its innerHtml and only then append it. If this is it, I'd post it as an answer.

Comment: The examplediv variable is of type object. I tried what you recommended before posting this and could not get the contents of the htmlStr variable to append as a child to the examplediv variable. Thanks for your feedback, though.

Comment: I am not sure you get my comment correctly. The examplediv has nothing to do, your argument to the appendChild is incorrect. You can't pass strings there and your htmlStr is a string.

Comment: I can see that by running typeof in the console. Thanks. I now have to figure out how to get the contents in htmlStr inside the example div then render. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Thanks! It worked with your recommendation:

Comment: Nice to hear that, I made an answer out of my comment.

Comment: I can now build out from what was created as a template. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As the error points out, [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) expects a [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), not a string. Use [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) with the argument `beforeend`:

```js
var model = {
  farm: {
    cow: "Moo!",
    pig: "Oink!",
    duck: "Quack!"
  }
};

var controller = {
  init: function() {
    farmView.init();
  },
  getBarn: function() {
    return model.farm;
  }
};


var farmView = {

  init: function() {
    this.barn = document.getElementById('farm');
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    var animals = controller.getBarn();
    this.barn.innerHTML = '';
    var htmlStr = '';
    htmlStr += '<span>' + model.farm.cow + '</span> <span>' + model.farm.pig + '</span>';

    this.barn.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlStr);
  }

};

controller.init();
```

```html
<div id="farm"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to say it clearly, what you pass as an argument to the `appendChild` is not of a Node type, it's a string.

You possibly meant to call `document.createElement` first to have a new element, then set its `innerHTML` and only then append it. This will work, as the newly created element will have a type accepted by the `appendChild`.